# High-speed flash with Tumax DPT586 AFZ-P: Why not manual mode?

Tags: flash, hotshoe-flash, manual-flash

I've just got a Tumax DPT586 AFZ-P flash gun for my Pentax K-50 DSLR.

When in high-speed sync mode, it only works via TTL metering.

Why?
How can I go into manual mode / manual power setting whilst in high-speed sync?
Is it a restriction on my specific flash gun, or does any HSS flash only allow HSS in conjunction with TTL exposure metering?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, but it appears that Pentax can only do HSS while in P-TTL mode.

Canon and Nikon do allow HSS in manual mode.

Answer (score 0):

For Pentax use an off camera flash to enable the use of manual pwr mode.   This requires two flashes.  Use one on camera flash as the control flash not master.  Note that the control flash will not contribute to the exposer.  All slave flashes can now be set to manual or p-ttl.  I use one control flash on the camera and three external flashes in manual mode adj'ed to 1/32 then set distance to subject for correct exposer.  I am able to get quick cycle time and correct exposer for my application.